# Cannot get the proper stereo from L/R pair

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

[image: LeftImage] [image: RightImage] [image: Stereo]

I run the following code with the left and the right images and get the strange result. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. First of all, why is it cropped and why is the disparity all one color?

```
CvStereoBMState *BMState = cvCreateStereoBMState();
assert(BMState != 0);
BMState->preFilterSize=41;
BMState->preFilterCap=31;
BMState->SADWindowSize=41;
BMState->minDisparity=-64;
BMState->numberOfDisparities=128;
BMState->textureThreshold=10;
BMState->uniquenessRatio=5;

CvMat* disp = cvCreateMat(image_pyramid[0][0]->height, image_pyramid[0][0]->width, CV_16S);
CvMat* vdisp = cvCreateMat(image_pyramid[0][0]->height, image_pyramid[0][0]->width, CV_8U);

cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM(image_pyramid[0][0], image_pyramid[1][0], disp, BMState);
cvNormalize(disp, vdisp, 0, 256, CV_MINMAX);
cvSaveImage("wowicantbelieveitsnotbutter.jpg", vdisp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the cropped image but I think that you should normalize it to range 0..1 and not to 0..255 since it is not 8 bit image.

Also maybe it looks cropped since the black values are actually negative.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing min disparity to zero this may help in your case(problem due to cropping). I did face the same problem. But I came with a solution of BMTuner. I have seen a video. Here I attach video this may help you with problem of cropping.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=FX7AMktf24E